# How to import excel file.xls into asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am trying to read data from excel.

```
if (fileext.Trim() == ".xls")
{
    connStr= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2";
}
else if (dosyauzanti.Trim() == ".xlsx")
{
    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
}
```

I can read Excel 2007 files. but I get an error when I try to read Excel 2003 files.

> External table is not in the expected format.

Comment: Have you attempted to look up the different in file extension between 2007 and 2003 files. Maybe done some research on if there are differences in reading them? Some more investigation might help you before reaching out here.

Comment: Look at your code really close, especially around the Extended Properties section and see if you notice any differences, itlooks like you're missing some quote marks.

Comment: two days I tried every way. I literal transcriptional samples of the internet connection was in commands, but I got the results are always the same.

Answer (score 1):

As commented correctly by sous2817 you are missing the quotes in your first connection string

```
connStr= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
```

Just to add more info to it, Excel 2007 vcersion files are Excel 12.0 and  Excel 2003 are Excel 8.0.